# How to get params from url and use it in pagination to go to the specific page according to the url? Angular 9

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination, angular-material, paginator

I'm new to angular and I want to do something. can you tell me How can I change the pagenator pageIndex and pageSize according to my url?
for example my url is:
http://localhost:4200/settings/domains/order_by=companies.id&direction=desc&page_size=5&page=1

this page=1 is when I go to the next page from page=0
so what I want to do now is when I copy the above link and paste it in a new page and enter I want the table to go to page 1 not page 0.
my ts file code to get the url params is like below:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     console.log(params);
      }
    });
}
```

and my pagination implementation in html is:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
  showFirstLastButtons
  [(pageSize)]="pageSize"
  [(pageIndex)]="pageIndex"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
  (page)="pageEvent = changePage($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

and here is the changePage method in ts file which I used to change the pagination:

```
changePage(event?: PageEvent) {
    this.queryParams.page_size = event.pageSize;
    this.queryParams.page = event.pageIndex;
    console.log(this.queryParams.page);

    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: this.queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
    });
    return event;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the queryParam object from the ActivatedRoute class.

```
constructor(private activatedRt: ActivatedRoute){
   this.activeRt.queryParams.subscribe(param => {
   let param = param["my-param"];
   let pageRequest = {
    pageSize: 5,
    pageIndex: param // if this is the page you are pulling from query param
   }
   this.changePage(pageRequest);
 });
}
```

Comment: Important to note that since `changePage` accepts PageEvents, you would have to `let pageRequest = new PageEvent()` and manually set the properties `pageSize` and `pageIndex` rather than the above implementation.